# Doing a big filesystem backup quickly

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems

There's a filesystem mounted on /home, which has 2.6PB storage room. Currently, there's 300TB+ data scattering under /home directory. I intend to backup the whole 300TB+ data **in daily manner** to /home/fs_backup, but I found the following command via `tar` is extremely slow:

```
cd /home/fs_backup && tar -cpf backup.tar.gz  --exclude="/home/fs_backup" --one-file-system "/home"
```

I estimate that it could only yield 10GB/min, which means the whole 300TB+ data cannot be backed-up in 24hours. Any idea how I could 'make a copy' of current data under /home no matter whether it is well-compressed - or even not compressed at all - or not in short time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you should look at rsync and do incremental backup, your first backup will be long there's no other way, but the other one should be fine.

Comment: but i need snapshot, like backup_20180801, backup_20180802, etc. any suggestions? @Kiwy

Comment: Is there any reason why you compress the output? `gtar` is slow but with additional compression, the time spend in `gtar` is not the dominant factor.

Comment: any other command recommended? @schily

Comment: The question is what you like to achieve in total. If you like no more than a backup, it is recommended to backup not the original filesystem but a `snapshot` from a specific state. How to make a snapshot depends on the filesystem in use.

Comment: if you need full daily backup of such a big FS, you should either use File system snapshot if supported by your FS or incremental backup. I don't think you will find any tool doing on the fly compression that will be much faster than your command. The important question here is what are your requirements in terms of retention and backup policy. If you need full daily backup, you will have to do more than rsync or tar to avoid performance issue and inconsistencies.

Comment: @Kiwy: If you like incremental backups, you need to use a tool that is known to do the task in a way that allows a restore. If you have `gtar` in mind, note that `gtar` is known that it manages incremental restores only for incremental backups with trivial differences.

Comment: @schily I have no tool in mind in this case as requirements are not express properly. Once done, I could recommand either `duplicity` or `rsync` or `lvm snapshot`

Comment: In former times, I did not recommend `rsync` since it did not support sparse files and nanoseconds in timestamps. This seems to have changed approx. 2 years ago. So if you like to make a copy to a remote machine, `rsync` now seems to be appropriate. For a real backup, this still seems to be different.

Comment: Did you consider that doing the backup is going to use a lot of bandwidth and is going to slow down whatever writes to the system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have already determined that you cannot backup the entire 300GB amount within the mandated 24 hour period you need to review your requirements.

At the file level, an incremental tool such as `star`, `duplicity`, or even `rsync`/`rsnapshot` may still take more than your one day to create the base backup but after that it should be considerably faster. Obviously, this will be dependent on the number and size of the files that are changed within each 24 hours backup period.

At the filesystem level, a snapshot may be sufficient for your needs (although this isn't really a backup), especially as you can then take a true backup from the snapshot at leisure without significant regard to the time taken for it to complete. As before, once the base backup has been laid down your incrementals may take considerably less time to produce.

You haven't specified how your backup should be stored, but for many small-ish files something like `rsnapshot` could be a good fit. (I use it for file-based backups of many of our internal fileservers since it allows us trivial access to individual files for recovery purposes.)

Incidentally, a backup to another disk on the same host shouldn't really be considered a safe backup. It would be far better to backup to a different host entirely. (If `/home/fs_backup` is a remote mount from a different server, seriously consider using `duplicity` or `rsync`/`rsnapshot` to communicate directly with the remote host rather than going through the remotely mounted filesystem.)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest method I am aware  of to do a backup is using `star` (see the latest version of this program in `schilytools`) as this program implements a ring buffer of arbitrary size that sits between a filesystem process and another process that does archive I/O. If the FIFO size is selected the right way, nearly all files are read using a single `read()` syscall and this makes it (together with it's optimized code) really fast.

This ring buffer is called `FIFO` and by default uses `8MB`, but may be told to use any size. The maximum useful value is half of the amount of `RAM` in the machine.

`star` also supports working incremental dumps and a full dump followed by an incremental dump is what I recommend to save the content of a filesystem in a way that in the last stage needs few time.

You may like to have a look at the man page: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html

Note that this man page recommends to do backups not from a live filesystem but from a `snapshot` at filesystem level.